# installing postgresql on two different cloudera clusters

Tags: postgresql, hbase, cloudera-cdh

We have two Cloudera Hbase Clusters(always ACTIVE), where application A, B write to one cluster and application C, D write to other cluster and the data on both of them is always sync and have all the data of all applications on each cluster. Now I want to install PostgreSQL on two clusters and need both the databases to be active and sync always. Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: Please disable your CAPS LOCK when posting here. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and typing in ALL CAPS will not get you help any faster. It's also rather rude to come here and start SHOUTING AT US to get attention. Thanks.

Comment: Its a title that is the reason I kept like that. I hope now it is fine, want me to make any more changes?